# SceneKit `projectPoint` issue after updating sceneView's pointOfView position property

Tags: scenekit

I have a loop inside which I update the position of the `sceneView`'s `pointOfView` property. I am surprised to see that after updating the position, the `projectPoint` method still returns the same values. What am I missing?

```
for phi in stride(from: 0, through: 90.0, by: 5) {
    for theta in stride(from: 0.0, through: 180.0, by: 5) {
        iter += 1
        print("Iteration \(iter)")
        let pos = sphericalToCartesian(r: 2.0, theta: theta, phi: phi)
        let a = SCNVector3(3,4,5)
        print("Projecting before updating pointOfView position \(sceneView.projectPoint(a))")

        sceneView.pointOfView!.position = pos
        print("Projecting after updating pointOfView position \(sceneView.projectPoint(a))")
```

Answer (score 1):

The values aren't updating because you're setting `sceneView.pointOfView.position` many times in a single render pass. The values aren't applied by SceneKit which is why `projectPoint()` always returns the same value.

If you enclose the two `projectPoint()` calls in `SCNTransaction` blocks with zero duration you will see that the values *are* changed:

```
SCNTransaction.begin()
SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 0
let pos = SCNVector3(Float(arc4random()), Float(arc4random()), Float(arc4random()))
let a = SCNVector3(3,4,5)
print("Projecting before updating pointOfView position \(scnView.projectPoint(a))")
scnView.pointOfView!.position = pos
SCNTransaction.commit()

SCNTransaction.begin()
SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 0
print("Projecting after updating pointOfView position \(scnView.projectPoint(a))")
SCNTransaction.commit()
```

However, this will slow down the execution time of your loop because `SCNTransaction` atomically applies all the changes to the presentation scene graph. When I tested it took twice as long.
If that's an issue then I suppose you'll have to roll your own implementation of `projectPoint()`